# Changing focus to another program Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get my application to change focus to any other windows it happens to mouse-over. I'm trying to implement some drag and drop functionality and all that seems to be missing is a change of focus as the mouse moves my application to another.

Here's my current test functionality (I do it on WM_MOUSEMOVE in the main callback prcedure right now for laughs)

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    HWND newHwnd = WindowFromPoint(pt);

    if (newHwnd != g_hSelectedWindow)
    {
        cout << "changing windows" << endl;
        cout << SetWindowPos(newHwnd, HWND_TOP, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE) << endl;
        g_hSelectedWindow = newHwnd;
    }

    CallWindowProc(listproc, hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
    break;
}
```

I tried using AllowSetForegroundWindow but it aid it couldn't find it in the given scope, but I had included .

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`AllowSetForegroundWindow` won't help, unless the *other* window tries to become the foreground window by calling `SetForegroundWindow`.

I am curious, if you need to bring this other window to the foreground, why not just call `SetForegroundWindow`on it directly?

*Update*: So this is the code that you need to get this working right:

```
HWND ResolveWindow(HWND hWnd)
{ /* Given a particular HWND, if it's a child, return the parent. Otherwise, if
   * the window has an owner, return the owner. Otherwise, just return the window
   */
    HWND hWndRet = NULL;

    if(::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CHILD)
        hWndRet = ::GetParent(hWnd);

    if(hWndRet == NULL)
        hWndRet = ::GetWindow(hWnd, GW_OWNER);

    if(hWndRet != NULL)
        return ResolveWindow(hWndRet);

    return hWnd;    
}

HWND GetTopLevelWindowFromPoint(POINT ptPoint)
{ /* Return the top-level window associated with the window under the mouse 
   * pointer (or NULL) 
   */
    HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(ptPoint);

    if(hWnd == NULL)
        return hWnd;    

    return ResolveWindow(hWnd);
}
```

Simply call `GetTopLevelWindowFromPoint(pt)` from your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler, and if you get a valid HWND back, then it will be a top-level window which can be brought to the foreground using SetForegroundWindow.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem you are encountering is that WindowFromPoint may return a window that cannot be made the foreground (i.e. a child window of a top-level window). I have updated my post with a pair of functions that you can use.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Nik! I'll give it a try today :D